# Some Azure Active Directory users are not able to login to Ubuntu Machines

Tags: ssh, authentication, ldap, active-directory

Some AD Users are not able to access Ubuntu machine in the domain, the error after trying to access the server via ssh I get in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
    Jun 14 11:50:36 SR sshd[1467842]: Invalid user UserName from 192.168.40.45 port 49378
Jun 14 11:50:37 SR sshd[1467842]: Connection reset by invalid user UserName 192.168.40.45 port 49378 [preauth]
Jun 14 11:50:45 SR sshd[1467955]: Invalid user UserName from 192.168.40.45 port 49379
Jun 14 11:50:50 SR sshd[1467955]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun 14 11:50:50 SR sshd[1467955]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.40.45
Jun 14 11:50:50 SR sshd[1467955]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.40.45 user=UserName
Jun 14 11:50:50 SR sshd[1467955]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user UserName: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
Jun 14 11:50:52 SR sshd[1467955]: Failed password for invalid user UserName from 192.168.40.45 port 49379 ssh2
```

It works for other users, but this specific user has joined recently and he can't access the Machine. Also changed the `ldap_idmap_range(min/max and size)`, to check if the issue was with ID Mapping, but it did not work out.
Even if the user tries to login via GUI, they get the following error:
[image]

I also tried to login through some other users ssh sessions  with `su - UserName`, but still I can't it gives back the error: `su: user UserName does not exist`
Below is sssd config file:

```
[sssd]
domains = "dn"
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/"dn"]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = "DN"
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = "dn"
# use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```

these are content of log files in `/var/log/sssd`
`/var/log/sssd/sssd_Domain-Name.log.1`:

```
(Date) [be[mydomain.com]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Date) [be[mydomain.com]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Date) [be[mydomain.com]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
(Date) [be[mydomain.com]] [orderly_shutdown] (0x0010): SIGTERM: killing children
```

and `sssd.log`:

```
(Date) [sssd] [service_signal_done] (0x0010): Unable to signal service [2]: No such file or directory
(Date) [sssd] [service_signal_done] (0x0010): Unable to signal service [2]: No such file or directory
(Date) [sssd] [service_signal_done] (0x0010): Unable to signal service [2]: No such file or directory
```

and basically nothing else, primary log files are empty
This is what I get for `sssd` status:

```
 sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-06-17 06:45:14 CEST; 3 days ago
   Main PID: 3371613 (sssd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 77003)
     Memory: 45.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/sssd.service
             ├─3371613 /usr/sbin/sssd -i --logger=files
             ├─3371615 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain mydomain.com --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             ├─3371616 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files
             └─3371617 /usr/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 --logger=files

Date MyServer sssd_be[3371615]: Backend is online
Date MyServer sssd[816515]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may>
Date MyServer sssd[816515]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may>
Date MyServer adcli[816513]: GSSAPI client step 1
Date MyServer adcli[816513]: GSSAPI client step 1
Date MyServer adcli[816513]: GSSAPI client step 1
Date MyServer sssd[816519]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may>
Date MyServer sssd[816519]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may>
Date MyServer sssd[816524]: tkey query failed: GSSAPI error: Major = Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may>
Date MyServer sssd_be[3371615]: Backend is offline
```

Comment: Is there some "exotic" character in the username? Could you add the "sssd config" to the question?

Comment: No there are no such characters in the username

Comment: With `sssd` I had often some problems with the cache. Have you tried `sss_cache -E` (see `man sss_cache`)? Any messages in `/var/log/sssd` which might help finding the problem?

Comment: I deleted the cache in `/var/lib/sssd/db` and then restarted the sssd service, but still the same issue

Comment: I use sssd with ldap, therefore I could only give some basic advise. Anything in `/var/log/sssd` ?

Comment: @marco I noticed something else also, that if I delete the `sssd` cache in `/var/lib/sssd/db`, the users that are able to login currently they won't be able to login either, but after recovering the cache they are able to login

Comment: I have no experience with sssd and AD. I just know from my sssd with ldap, that usually the cache is a problem. If deleting the cache locks out others, there is something wrong with the config. And connecting Linux to whatever Windows works usually only temporary, till Microsoft decides to change something without notice. That's why I duplicated my AD in openldap.

Comment: Maybe you get something in the sssd logs if you set `debug_level = 9` in the domain config. I guess the problem has something to do with the kerberos keytab. Have you changed hostnames or is something in DNS missing? Update Keytab? Something in samba changed?

Comment: I set the debug level to 9, and still was not getting anything. I will check on the hostname and keytab and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with sss cache, I delete the cache with `sss_cache -E` and restarted the machine and seems everything is working fine, I guess even if I hadn't restarted the machine it would have started working, it needed some time for the changes to be applied